# What is the relationship between ADS-B IN/OUT and different mode transponders？

Tags: ads-b

What is the relationship between ADS-B IN/OUT system and different mode transponders? Can a aircraft with mode A or C transponder have the ADS-B in/out capability, that is getting more detailed surrounding traffic information like ID, position, velocity and broadcasting its own ID, position, altitude etc.

Comment: While it is normally integrated into a single transponder, there is no requirement to have a Mode A/C transponder to be able to also have an ADS-B in/out capability. I'm not sure what you are asking? Mode A/C transponders are not ADS-B capable by themselves, ADS-B is a separate protocol that has to be specifically supported. Are you asking about in-cockpit displays? ADS-B in display depends on the other avionics you have in the aircraft...

Comment: @Ron Beyer thanks, Ron. So mode A/C transponder can not be a component for a ADS-B IN/Out system. What onboard equipment can get the traffic data thru the mode A/C transponder equipped on another aircraft?

Comment: And what onboard equipment required for ADS-B in function to get the data broadcasted by the mode-S transponder on another aircraft?

Comment: TCAS is the only system I know of that allows one aircraft to show data from another through mode a/c transponders.